# ¿Cómo incluir múltiples niveles de propiedades con Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Al realizar un query con Entity Framework uno puede cargar no solo la entidad sino también las entidades relacionadas a esta con el método `Include`, por ejemplo teniendo un modelo con clientes, órdenes y productos:

```
dbContext.Cliente
         .Include(x => x.Ordenes)
         .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
```

De esta manera trae la información de un cliente y sus órdenes en un solo query, pero ¿cómo hacer si quiero cargar la información relacionada a las órdenes también?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Para EF 6**

Si son propiedades de navegación simple, se encadenan las propiedades con un punto.  Si la propiedad es una colección se utiliza el método `Select` en combinación con `Include`:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

query
    .Include(x => x.Propiedad1.Propiedad2)
    .Include(x => x.Coleccion.Select(y => y.Propiedad))
```

Ver la [documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx#Anchor_1) para más ejemplos.

El namespace `System.Data.Entity` es necesario para usar la versión de `Include` que acepta una expresión lambda.

---

**Para EF Core**

Utilizar el método [`ThenInclude`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/ef/core/querying/related-data#including-multiple-levels)

```
query.Include(x => x.Coleccion)
     .ThenInclude(x => x.Propiedad);
```